# To thorough clean/to clean thoroughly/to thoroughly clean?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

It is essential **to thorough clean/to clean thoroughly/to thoroughly clean** the machine after each use.

Choose the best option to make the sentence perfect.
I am a bit confused here because I believe each one of them makes the sentence proper. I do not think if there is any rule for this. If yes, please let me know.
Suggestions please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Note the difference:

Correct:

> It is essential to thoroughly clean the machine.

Incorrect:

> It is essential to to clean thoroughly the machine.

The second example can be correctly constructed like this:

> It is essential to to clean the machine thoroughly.

Even so, the first example sounds slightly better to me.

Answer (score 0):

This is a difficult question to answer because it is more a question of style than a question of grammar.

The first option is the worst.  "Thorough" is an adjective.  It is not a suitable modifier for a verb.  One way or another, you should use the adverb "thoroughly".  As I judge these options, this is the only one with bad grammar.

The last option is a split infinitive.  Old-fashioned style guides recommend (or even demand) that you avoid split infinitives.  Personally, I find this to be a good option.  I cannot speak for whatever style guide you might be required to follow.

The remaining option avoids the split infinitive, but it poses a different stylistic problem.  It places the adverb between the infinitive and its object.  I have to recommend that you avoid that.  I have no idea whether your style guide considers that to be a problem.

The best option is an option that you don't list.  Place the adverb after the infinitive's direct object:

> It is essential **to clean** the machine **thoroughly** after each use.

However, on a multiple choice test, you cannot choose an option which is not provided.